# Uncheck all button not working with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

i've been trying to fiddle with this for an hour or two now and am coming up stumped as to why it's not working. Perhaps some of you enlightened people can help nudge me into the correct direction!

I'm trying to create a simple function that will take all the checkboxes inside of my PHP and uncheck them on the click of a button.

I found some code that had already been used here on stackoverflow, but after tweaking it for the past while, i've been unsuccessful in getting it to work with PHP.

```
<?
include "cons2.php";
db_connect();

print "
<script>
function uncheckAll(){
$(\"input[type='checkbox']:checked\").prop(\"checked\",false)
}
</script>";

print"
<input type='checkbox'/>
<input type='checkbox'/>
<input type='checkbox'/>
<input type='checkbox'/>
<input type='checkbox'/>
<input type='button' onclick='uncheckAll()' value=\"clear\" />";
?>
```

I've tried to get this to work by putting the script outside of the PHP, inside a header tag, but it doesn't seem to help much. Thank you in advance for any replies you can give, they are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Looks like you're using jQuery, but I don't see you including jquery.js anywhere in your HTML; is jQuery definitely available on the page?

Comment: I am not, as far as the code went that I based this off, there was no mention of a jquery.js, would I need to add that function into the jquery.js?

Comment: no, but you do need to load jquery itself to have `$()` available...

Comment: @oxguy3 Good call, are you clarevoyant?

Comment: To be able to use jQuery, you need to have the jQuery library included in your HTML. [Here's an intro tutorial to jQuery](http://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/) that shows how to do this.

Comment: Haha @RiggsFolly, just a lucky guess I spose :P

Comment: Hah, sounds like it will work, thanks a lot guys, talking with my co-worker, we've got the jquery set up, he just never told me about it :P Thanks for the quick replies, i'll update it it works

Comment: Also, I apologize about the title, it saved a title from an old question I figured out myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to use jQuery:

```
function uncheckAll(){
    var checkboxes = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    for(var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++){
        if(checkboxes[i].type == "checkbox"){
            checkboxes[i].checked = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Beauty answer, short, easy and nicely working. Keep up the good work :)

Comment: I'm not really sure how to integrate that into my PHP

Answer (score 2):

Use jQuery :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#check-all').on('click', function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      $('.check').each(function() {
        this.checked = true;
      });
    } else {
      $('.check').each(function() {
        this.checked = false;
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Check 1 :
<input class="check" type="checkbox">
<br>Check 2 :
<input class="check" type="checkbox">
<br>Check 3 :
<input class="check" type="checkbox">
<br>Check 4 :
<input class="check" type="checkbox">
<br>Check 5 :
<input class="check" type="checkbox">
<br>

<br>
<br>Check All :
<input id="check-all" type="checkbox">
```

Comment: This is the first time I have seen this snippet stuff used where it actually made sense and actually did something.

Comment: As you can see it has nothing to do with PHP, its done using jQuery.

Comment: The only issue i'm having is, my input boxes are inside of a PHP format, while my script is outside of the PHP, will that effect it? Because it doesn't seem to want to fully function with the inputs inside the php.

Comment: it's fine. Let php generate the checkboxes, jQuery will handle the clicking part.

Comment: can cut this down to `$('#check-all').on('change', function() { $('.check').prop('checked', this.checked) ; });`